# How can I create a game as a live wallpaper?

Tags: android

I have a space shooter game for Android and I want to implement it as a live wallpaper. Any ideas on how this can be done?

Or better yet can anyone help me / provide a template that calls a "ship" object that fires missile? I'll do the rest from there onwards. I just need it as a starting point for learning Android.

Comment: I too enjoy cutting my battery life in half.

Comment: XD XD XD aha ha ha!

Answer (score 1):

The first Google hit I got for [live wallpaper api android](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/live-wallpapers.html) gives a good overview and links to example code.

Comment: It only refers to the Cube Live Wallpaper which basically deals with actual drawing on canvas, what I wanted to achieve is to call a class (Ship class) into the Wallpaper. ^^,

Comment: @user943974, why does the obvious approach of calling the Ship constructor not work?

Comment: I'm calling the ship class inside the c = holder.lockCanvas which goes something like: shipS.draw(c); where shipS = the ship class. Can you please show me the right way of "calling the Ship constructor" it might be the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: @user943974, I get the impression that the question you asked isn't really the real question, which is "What's wrong with the code I've written?". How about you create a small but complete program which demonstrates your problem and (if that doesn't in itself help you solve it) post on StackOverflow?

Comment: I thought it would be more convenient if I could see a Live Wallpaper Template that does something like my specification. Then, I could adapt from there, configure my missile, movement, speed classes to be compatible with the one provided. ^^,